# (Solved) How to change the font size of the android studio itself

Tags: android-studio

[image]

Help please I can't do anything with this hug size. the size of the code is fine but everything else is hug.

Comment: I wanted to accepted my answer but it side "You can accept your own answer in 2 days"

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. It's showing in the image below
[image]